# to understatnd substr on awk

Tags: awk

I want to understand how works this line, not sure if I got it.

```
ls -l | awk '
{
  k=0;
  for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));
  if (k)
    printf("%0o ",k);
  print
}'
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: So what part do you get and what do you not?

Comment: so what do and what don't you understand?

Comment: Check out [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), as well as the [documentation for awk](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk).

Comment: The "for" cicle:  for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
    k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));
  if (k)
    printf("%0o ",k);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code converts the standard `-rwxrwxrwx` style of permissions generated by `ls -l` into octal numbers that could be used with `chmod`, and prepends them onto each line.

For example, it would make the following conversions:

```
-rwxr-xr--
 7  5  4

-rwx-wx---
 7  3  0
```

Note that this awk script does NOT support sticky or setuid bits.

Comment: I know it, but I want to know/understand how it's working  :)

Comment: If it's already working, then it's not really on-topic for StackOverflow.  :-)  In future, if you know what something does, and you want help figuring out how, try playing with it until it breaks, then ask for help in fixing it.